# Remove address Bar when Parsing an external URL through intent android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, webview

I am initiating an intent which is parsing an URI and showing the content on Webview but the webview has an address bar , which i want to remove. Since i am not loading the URl on activity there is no point in giving android:NOtitle in activity. below is code how i am calling an web view.

```
Intent viewMessage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse(messages.get(position).getLink().toExternalForm()));

            this.startActivity(viewMessage);
```

Thank you in advacnce

Comment: I think i got what i was looking for......[link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/c0b2b54e6df03125?fwc=1&pli=1)

Comment: It would be great if you can add that as an answer and close this question.

Comment: i got it form ...http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8f71c68b62455c52#